# Scraping table-index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping a table in Python, I'm trying to capture each field so I can manipulate which fields I want to display. I've used a setup like this before but this time I'm getting an index out of range error.

I've pulled the entire table no problem, but like I said I want to option to only show specific fields. I would also like the headers from each section (e.g. New Bank, etc.).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

print('Scraping NH Dept of Banking...')
print()

NHurl = 'https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm'
NHr = requests.get(NHurl, headers = headers)

NHsoup = BeautifulSoup(NHr.text, 'html.parser')

NHlist = []

for tr in NHsoup.find_all('tr'):
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    print("Test: %s, Test: %s, Test: %s\n" % \
          (tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[2].text))
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas uses bs4 under the hood on the `.read_html()` function. If you see a `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags, let pandas do the heavy lifting for you:

```
import pandas as pd

NHurl = 'https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm'

df = pd.read_html(NHurl)[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print (df.to_string())
                                       Date Requested                         Financial Institution Name                                           Location                                 Determination Date
0                                                 NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
1                                            New Bank                                           New Bank                                           New Bank                                           New Bank
2                                            12/11/18                                  The Millyard Bank                                                NaN                                                NaN
3                         Interstate Bank Combination                        Interstate Bank Combination                        Interstate Bank Combination                        Interstate Bank Combination
4                                            01/16/19  Optima Bank & Trust Company with and into Camb...                                     Portsmouth, NH                                           03/29/19
5                                        Acquisitions                                       Acquisitions                                       Acquisitions                                       Acquisitions
6                                                 NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
7                                         Conversions                                        Conversions                                        Conversions                                        Conversions
8                                                 NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
9                                   Change in Control                                  Change in Control                                  Change in Control                                  Change in Control
10                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
11  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...  Amendment to Articles of Agreement or Incorpor...
12                                           11/26/18                         John Hancock Trust Company                                         Boston, MA                                           01/14/19
13                                           12/04/18                              Franklin Savings Bank                                       Franklin, NH                                           01/28/19
14                                           12/12/18                         MFS Heritage Trust Company                                         Boston, MA                                           01/28/19
15                                           02/25/19                          Ankura Trust Company, LLC                                      Fairfield, CT                                           03/22/19
16                                            4/25/19                   Woodsville Guaranty Savings Bank                                     Woodsville, NH                                           06/04/19
17                                            5/10/19                                   AB Trust Company                                       New York, NY                                           06/04/19
18                               Reduction in Capital                               Reduction in Capital                               Reduction in Capital                               Reduction in Capital
19                                           03/07/19                                       Primary Bank                                        Bedford, NH                                           04/10/19
20                                Amendment to Bylaws                                Amendment to Bylaws                                Amendment to Bylaws                                Amendment to Bylaws
21                                           12/10/18                             Northeast Credit Union                                     Porstmouth, NH                                           02/25/19
22                                            2/25/19                         Members First Credit Union                                     Manchester, NH                                           04/05/19
23                                            4/24/19                                    St. Mary's Bank                                     Manchester, NH                                           05/30/19
24                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
25                           Interstate Branch Office                           Interstate Branch Office                           Interstate Branch Office                           Interstate Branch Office
26                                           01/23/19                Newburyport Five Cents Savings Bank                     141 Portsmouth Ave  Exeter, NH                                           02/01/19
27                                           03/08/19                                   One Credit Union                                        Newport, NH                                           03/29/19
28                                           03/01/19                            JPMorgan Chase Bank, NA                                         Nashua, NH                                           04/04/19
29                                           03/26/19                                       Mascoma Bank                                        Lebanon, NH                                           04/09/19
30                                           04/24/19                Newburyport Five Cents Savings Bank                       321 Lafayette Rd  Hampton NH                                           05/08/19
31                   Interstate Branch Office Closure                   Interstate Branch Office Closure                   Interstate Branch Office Closure                   Interstate Branch Office Closure
32                                           02/15/19                                 The Provident Bank                      321 Lafayette Rd  Hampton, NH                                           02/25/19
33                                  New Branch Office                                  New Branch Office                                  New Branch Office                                  New Branch Office
34                                           12/07/18                              Bank of New Hampshire                16-18 South Main Street  Concord NH                                           01/02/19
35                                             3/4/19                              Triangle Credit Union         360 Daniel Webster Highway,  Merrimack, NH                                           03/11/19
36                                           04/03/19                  Bellwether Community Credit Union          425-453 Commercial Street  Manchester, NH                                           04/17/19
37                                           06/11/19                                       Primary Bank                        23 Crystal Avenue  Derry NH                                           06/11/19
38                              Branch Office Closure                              Branch Office Closure                              Branch Office Closure                              Branch Office Closure
39                                            5/15/19                             Northeast Credit Union                                      Merrimack, NH                                           05/21/19
40                         New Loan Production Office                         New Loan Production Office                         New Loan Production Office                         New Loan Production Office
41                                           04/08/19                            Community National Bank   367 Route 120, Unit B-5  Lebanon, NH  03766-1430                                           04/15/19
42                     Loan Production Office Closure                     Loan Production Office Closure                     Loan Production Office Closure                     Loan Production Office Closure
43                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
44                 Loan Production Office Relocations                 Loan Production Office Relocations                 Loan Production Office Relocations                 Loan Production Office Relocations
45                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
46                          Branch Office Relocations                          Branch Office Relocations                          Branch Office Relocations                          Branch Office Relocations
47                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN                                                NaN
48                                Trade Name Requests                                Trade Name Requests                                Trade Name Requests                                Trade Name Requests
49                                           04/16/19                         John Hancock Trust Company  To use trade name "Manulife Investment Managem...                                           04/24/19
50                                  New Trust Company                                  New Trust Company                                  New Trust Company                                  New Trust Company
51                                           02/19/19                              Janney Trust Co., LLC                                                NaN                                                NaN
52                                           02/25/19         Darwin Trust Company of New Hampshire, LLC                                                NaN                                                NaN
53                       Dissolution of Trust Company                       Dissolution of Trust Company                       Dissolution of Trust Company                       Dissolution of Trust Company
54                                           09/19/17          Cambridge Associates Fiduciary Trust, LLC                                         Boston, MA                                           02/05/19
55                               Trust Office Closure                               Trust Office Closure                               Trust Office Closure                               Trust Office Closure
56                                            5/10/19                              Charter Trust Company                                      Rochester, NH                                           05/20/19
57                                   New Trust Office                                   New Trust Office                                   New Trust Office                                   New Trust Office
58                                           02/25/19                          Ankura Trust Company, LLC  140 Sherman Street, 4th Floor  Fairfield, CT 0...                                           03/22/19
59                         Relocation of Trust Office                         Relocation of Trust Office                         Relocation of Trust Office                         Relocation of Trust Office
60                                           01/23/19        Geode Capital Management Trust Company, LLC  Relocate from: One Post Office Square, 20th Fl...                                           02/01/19
61                                           03/15/19                       Drivetrain Trust Company LLC  Relocate from: 630 3rd Avenue, 21st Flr  New Y...                                           03/29/19
62                                           04/14/19                      Boston Partners Trust Company  Relocate from: 909 Third Avenue  New York, NY ...                                           04/23/19
```

Comment: pandas uses bs4 under the head for read_html? That would be interesting - is it in docs?

Comment: @QHarr it is mentioned in the docs. Let me look and I'll post the link. EDIT: actually uses lxml to parse, but opts to bs4 if that fails. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.read_html.html

Comment: flavor : str or None, container of strings

The parsing engine to use. ‘bs4’ and ‘html5lib’ are synonymous with each other, they are both there for backwards compatibility. The default of None tries to use lxml to parse and if that fails it falls back on bs4 + html5lib

Answer (score 0):

Your code assume that `len(tds) >= 3` but it looks like it is not true

Comment: but how do I find out what is in range? Is that method just not possible here?

Comment: `print(','.join([td.text for td in tds]))` - Just loop over the tds and create a string

Answer (score 0):

For scraping the headers AND the data you can use selector `tr.select('td, th')`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}

print('Scraping NH Dept of Banking...')
print()

NHurl = 'https://www.nh.gov/banking/corporate-activities/index.htm'
NHr = requests.get(NHurl, headers = headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(NHr.text, 'lxml')

rows = [[td.text.strip() for td in tr.select('td, th')] for tr in soup.select('tr') if tr.select('td, th')]

import textwrap
from itertools import zip_longest

rows = [*zip(*zip_longest(*rows))]

for row in rows:
    for data in row:
        if data is None:
            data = "-"
        print('{: ^30}'.format(textwrap.shorten(data, 30, placeholder='...')), end='║')
    print()
```

Prints:

```
        Date Requested        ║  Financial Institution Name  ║           Location           ║      Determination Date      ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
           New Bank           ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           12/11/18           ║      The Millyard Bank       ║                              ║                              ║
 Interstate Bank Combination  ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           01/16/19           ║Optima Bank & Trust Company...║        Portsmouth, NH        ║           03/29/19           ║
         Acquisitions         ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
         Conversions          ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
      Change in Control       ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
 Amendment to Articles of...  ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           11/26/18           ║  John Hancock Trust Company  ║          Boston, MA          ║           01/14/19           ║
           12/04/18           ║    Franklin Savings Bank     ║         Franklin, NH         ║           01/28/19           ║
           12/12/18           ║  MFS Heritage Trust Company  ║          Boston, MA          ║           01/28/19           ║
           02/25/19           ║  Ankura Trust Company, LLC   ║        Fairfield, CT         ║           03/22/19           ║
           4/25/19            ║Woodsville Guaranty Savings...║        Woodsville, NH        ║           06/04/19           ║
           5/10/19            ║       AB Trust Company       ║         New York, NY         ║           06/04/19           ║
     Reduction in Capital     ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           03/07/19           ║         Primary Bank         ║         Bedford, NH          ║           04/10/19           ║
     Amendment to Bylaws      ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           12/10/18           ║    Northeast Credit Union    ║        Porstmouth, NH        ║           02/25/19           ║
           2/25/19            ║  Members First Credit Union  ║        Manchester, NH        ║           04/05/19           ║
           4/24/19            ║       St. Mary's Bank        ║        Manchester, NH        ║           05/30/19           ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
   Interstate Branch Office   ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           01/23/19           ║  Newburyport Five Cents...   ║141 Portsmouth Ave Exeter, NH ║           02/01/19           ║
           03/08/19           ║       One Credit Union       ║         Newport, NH          ║           03/29/19           ║
           03/01/19           ║   JPMorgan Chase Bank, NA    ║          Nashua, NH          ║           04/04/19           ║
           03/26/19           ║         Mascoma Bank         ║         Lebanon, NH          ║           04/09/19           ║
           04/24/19           ║  Newburyport Five Cents...   ║ 321 Lafayette Rd Hampton NH  ║           05/08/19           ║
 Interstate Branch Office...  ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           02/15/19           ║      The Provident Bank      ║ 321 Lafayette Rd Hampton, NH ║           02/25/19           ║
      New Branch Office       ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           12/07/18           ║    Bank of New Hampshire     ║  16-18 South Main Street...  ║           01/02/19           ║
            3/4/19            ║    Triangle Credit Union     ║360 Daniel Webster Highway,...║           03/11/19           ║
           04/03/19           ║Bellwether Community Credit...║ 425-453 Commercial Street... ║           04/17/19           ║
           06/11/19           ║         Primary Bank         ║  23 Crystal Avenue Derry NH  ║           06/11/19           ║
    Branch Office Closure     ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           5/15/19            ║    Northeast Credit Union    ║        Merrimack, NH         ║           05/21/19           ║
  New Loan Production Office  ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           04/08/19           ║   Community National Bank    ║  367 Route 120, Unit B-5...  ║           04/15/19           ║
Loan Production Office Closure║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
  Loan Production Office...   ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
  Branch Office Relocations   ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
                              ║                              ║                              ║                              ║
     Trade Name Requests      ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           04/16/19           ║  John Hancock Trust Company  ║To use trade name "Manulife...║           04/24/19           ║
      New Trust Company       ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           02/19/19           ║    Janney Trust Co., LLC     ║                              ║                              ║
           02/25/19           ║Darwin Trust Company of New...║                              ║                              ║
 Dissolution of Trust Company ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           09/19/17           ║   Cambridge Associates...    ║          Boston, MA          ║           02/05/19           ║
     Trust Office Closure     ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           5/10/19            ║    Charter Trust Company     ║        Rochester, NH         ║           05/20/19           ║
       New Trust Office       ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           02/25/19           ║  Ankura Trust Company, LLC   ║  140 Sherman Street, 4th...  ║           03/22/19           ║
  Relocation of Trust Office  ║              -               ║              -               ║              -               ║
           01/23/19           ║ Geode Capital Management...  ║  Relocate from: One Post...  ║           02/01/19           ║
           03/15/19           ║ Drivetrain Trust Company LLC ║  Relocate from: 630 3rd...   ║           03/29/19           ║
           04/14/19           ║Boston Partners Trust Company ║ Relocate from: 909 Third...  ║           04/23/19           ║
```